# Are solutions of $\Delta f \leq -a^2 f$ constant on a compact manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, laplacian, eigenfunctions

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a closed (compact, without boundary) smooth Riemannian manifold and let $\Delta = -\operatorname{div} \operatorname{grad}$ be the induced Laplacian on $M$ (so that the eigenvalue problem is written in the form $\Delta u = \lambda u$). My question is simple: let $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $a \neq 0$, and suppose that $f \in C^2(M)$ satisfies the inequality

$$\Delta f(x) \leq -a^2 f(x) \quad x \in M.$$

**Question**: Does it follow that $f$ is constant? Does it depend on $a$?

**What I have done so far**: Let $x_0$ be a point of maximum of $f$. It must hold that $\Delta f(x_0) \geq 0$. So,

$$ 0 \leq \Delta f(x_0) \leq -a^2 f(x_0) \implies f(x_0) \leq 0.$$

Thus, $f(x) \leq 0$ for every $x \in M$.

Another thing to notice: no eigenfunction of $\Delta$ satisfies the inequality, unless it is a nonpositive constant.

Comment: I may be too tired for math now but doesn't the new function $g(x)=-f(x)$ also satisfy the inequality which gives $g(x) \le 0$ be your argument, hence the inequality implies $f(x)=0$?

Comment: I don't think it works...$g(x)$ satisfies the opposite inequality

Comment: I am assuming a specific $f$ satisfies the inequality, not every $f$.

Comment: $f = -2 + \cos t$ and $a=1$ work on $S^1$. And in general since $f$ and $\Delta f$ are both bounded, you can always subtract a number big enough from $f$ to find a solution.

Comment: If you start with the assumption that $f \ge 0$, then your argument works.

Comment: Why does your last statement hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one requires that $f$ is nonnegative, then $f\equiv0$ on $M.$ To see this, it suffices to multiply the inequality by $f$ and then integrate by parts. However in general, only the differential inequality cannot ensure  $f$ to be a constant. In fact, given any negative $h\in C^\infty(M),$ we can solve the linear equation $-\Delta_M u+a^2u=h$ on $M.$ To prove this, we consider the energy functional $$E(u)=\int_M\frac{1}{2}|\nabla_Mu|^2+\frac{a^2}{2}u^2-hud\mu_g,\quad u\in X:=W^{1,2}(M),$$ where $X$ is the Banach space with norm $$\|u\|=\left(\int_M|\nabla_Mu|^2+a^2u^2d\mu_g\right)^{1/2}.$$ The (unique) critical point of $E$ gives a solution of above equation. One can easily check that $E\in C^\infty(X,\mathbf R)$ is convex and proper, that is, $$\lim_{\|u\|\to\infty}E(u)=+\infty.$$ Thus, there is some $u_0\in X$ such that $$E(u_0)=\inf_{u\in X}E(u).$$ The elliptic regularity theorem deduces that $u_0\in C^\infty(M)$ if $M$ is smooth. Thus, $u_0$ cannot be constant if $h$ is chosen to be non-constant.